# Laravel 5.2: Настройка .htaccess для доступа к файлам storage

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

При загрузки файлов изображений на сервер, после валидации и их обработки, скрипт помещает файлы в хранилище: `{папка_проекта}/storage/app/images/{год}/{месяц}/{день}/{час}/{имя_файла}`.

В итоге путь к файлам изображений на сервере относительно папки `{папка_проекта}/storage/app/` будет такого вида: `images/2016/02/25/02/4fd3f8100a2cca983362f3ec6c9aaaff.jpg`.

Какие я вижу варианты:

1. Для прямого доступа к этим файлам по Url, думаю практичней всего будет расширить файл `{папка_проекта}/public/.htaccess`.
2. Или же лучше отдавать файлы изображений через роутеры/контроллеры? - этот вариант знаю как реализовать, но, нравится меньше, по скольку так понимаю будет хавать больше ресурсов сервера.

P.S. Я не силён в .htaccess, пожалуйста пишите готовый набор инструкций для решения этой задачи, знаю, что тут выйдет примерно несколько строк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете настроить стоража в config/filesystems.php

```
 'disks' => [
...
        'images' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('images'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
...
```

В результате у вас все полетит в папку public
Далее в контроллере добавляете логику для создание нужных подкаталогов число/месяц/время и т.д

```
 if (!Storage::disk('images')->exists($directory)) {
            Storage::disk('images')->makeDirectory($directory);
        }
```

В итоге все ваши файлы будут доступны через стандартный каталог public